# How to convert continous XML to indented XML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, vb.net

I have an xml

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph TextAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Arial" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User"><Run FontSize="15">Foo Bar</Run></Paragraph></FlowDocument>
```

I want to convert this to

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Arial" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User">
        <Run FontSize="15">Foo Bar</Run>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

I don't know how to do this? This XML is generated dynamically by `XamlWriter.Save` and what this function returns becomes text of a textbox like this

```
TxtBox1.Text = XamlWriter.Save(MyFlowDocument);
```

Comment: You mean, just for viewing or in code?

Comment: @IlyaKogan: Read updated question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the text into an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (see [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx)) and then use [XDocument.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) on the new instance.